# How to load data of desired no of div by ajax

Tags: jquery, iphone, ajax, wordpress

on my home page, I want to display only one or two `<div class="block" id="block-mid">` and 
load remain div by ajax. So the page loading time will decrease. I want this functionality on iphone view also. I am using wordpress cms in which i am using `allegro` premium theme for my site.

```
<div class="block" id="block-mid">
  <div><img src="abc.jpg" /></div>
  <div><p>Lorem ipsum dolar sit amet</p></div>
</div>

<div class="block" id="block-mid">
  <div><img src="abca.jpg" /></div>
  <div><p>Lorem ipsum dolar sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolar sit amet</p></div>
</div>

<div class="block" id="block-mid">
  <div><img src="abc.jpg" /></div>
  <div><p>Lorem ipsum dolar sit amet. psum dolar sit amet</p></div>
</div>

<div class="block" id="block-mid">
  <div><img src="abcd.jpg" /></div>
  <div><p>Lorem ipsum dolar sit amet1233455</p></div>
</div>
```

The above div 's are coming through default static block. Thanks in advance for any help or suggestion.
Pls ask if more information required.